# PHP header() function to C://

Tags: php, header

**Short version:**
 How can I relocate to `C:\Abyss Web Server\htdocs\database\pfs\max\files\public\sdf.png` using `header()`?


**Thorough version:**
Currently I'm stuck with this piece of code:

```
header("Location: ".ROOT_URL."\database\pfs\\".$_GET["u"]."\\files\public\\".$c);
```

(Not completely in context, but it's not needed in this case, since I've managed to track the cause on my own).
`$c` is the filename, declared in context, and `$_GET["u"]` is the "owner's" name. ROOT_URL is defined as: `define("ROOT_URL", "file://\Abyss%20Web%20Server\htdocs");`, which simply is the path to the server directory (I've also tried with `define("ROOT_URL", "C:/\Abyss%20Web%20Server\htdocs");` , but there's no luck there either). Anyways, with this, I want the user to be able of downloading uploaded files by `$_GET["u"]`. The problem is though, that I everytime get a 404 error... And, from experimenting a bit, I've come to the conclusion that the header() function isn't handling the redirect well.

Not sure why this is happening exactly, but I assume that it has something to do with `file://` or `c:/`. My server is currently hosted locally, and therefore I need to use these methods instead (for so long). Answer would be highly appreciated, as I've been stuck with this for a while now...

Comment: I don't get it. Are you trying to make a PHP site run without a web server?

Comment: I have a locally hosted web server with working PHP.

Answer (score 3):

If it is a local file system link, you need to prepend the `file://` protocol prefix:

```
header('Location: file://C:\\path\\to\\file');
```

If you omit that, the client (browser) will interprete it as `http://C:\\path\\to\\file`

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at it when I get access to my computer.

Comment: Still doesn't work. This is the content that fills the parameter in `header()`, without any predefined constants or variables: `Location: file://C:\\Abyss Web Server\\htdocs\\database\\pfs\\max\\files\\public\\sdf.png` (I've tried both with and without `%20` characters). The correct path is: `C:\Abyss Web Server\htdocs\database\pfs\max\files\public\sdf.png`. I still end up with the same result in all browsers.

Comment: @Max I unfortunately have no Windows for testing. Important is the `file://` prefix and a proper masking of the windows directory separator (I assume).. Try to open a local html file with right click "open in browser" .. Then you can see how the urls should look like

Comment: I was **certain** of that it didn't work in any browser when checking last time, but now it does in Chrome... I'm not receiving HTTP 404 errors either, just "can't view page"-ones. Maybe it has to do with the clients reading process?

Comment: @Max I've tested on Linux but without success. Looks like a browser restriction as the [RFC for HTTP](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30) does not say anything about restrictions

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your help. I asked someone in real life, and they said that I can move the files to root and take it from there. Didn't really solve THIS exact problem, but it works.